# Unable to read a column of an excel by Column Name using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiiOA.png)

I want to read values of the column 'Site Name' but in this sheet, the location of this tab is not fixed.
I tried,

```
df = pd.read_excel('TestFile.xlsx', sheet_name='List of problematic Sites', usecols=['Site Name'])
```

but got value error,

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['RBS Name']
```

The output should be, `List of RBS=['TestSite1', 'TestSite2',........]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reading the excel columns by this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')

for i in df.index:
   print(df['Site Name'][i])
```

Comment: Actually, the column location is not fixed. So we can't used column number to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check dataframe without mentioning column name while reading excel file.
Then try to read column names.

Code is as below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('TestFile.xlsx', sheet_name='List of problematic Sites')

print(df.head)
print(df.columns)
```